# quitting heroku app from within python script

Tags: python, heroku, discord, discord.py, sys

I have a Heroku app running a `discord.py` bot and I want to make a remote shutdown command. If I was running from `bash` i could just do this with `exit()` or `sys.exit()` but neither of these work in Heroku as the app will startup again after the exit() because it thinks its a crash. I tried to use `os.system` but that didn't work either.

Here is my code:

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def remoteshutdown(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Shutting down")
    exit()
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `bot.close()` or `bot.logout()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remotely shutdown your bot consider using `bot.logout()`.
Replace your code with this:

```
@bot.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def remoteshutdown(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Shutting down")
    # Shuts down the bot
    await bot.logout()
```

I would also recommend that you use a better hosting service like LawlietHost, they provide both free and premium hosting. https://discord.gg/37HuZHMzgq